# Strange object expected error when using .html

Tags: jquery

This all seems to work great just the really strange thing is when I try to reference the var with .html('g'+index) it throws an object expected error. I guessing building the var isn't the best thing?

```
var g0 = "<?php getFiles("gallery/Audience"); ?>";
var g1 = "<?php getFiles("gallery/Exhibition"); ?>";
var g2 = "<?php getFiles("gallery/registration"); ?>";
var g3 = "<?php getFiles("gallery/Speakers"); ?>";

$(".galleryButton").each(function (index) {
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('#galleria').html();                              
        $('#galleria').html('g'+index);
        initiateGallery();
    }).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#002E53');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#000');
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the line `$('#galleria').html();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use eval to get the value of the variable gx.

```
$(this).click(function(){
    $('#galleria').html();                              
    $('#galleria').html(eval('g'+index));
    initiateGallery();
})
```

But as eval is evil you should use a switch-case to get the variables:

```
$(this).click(function(){
    $('#galleria').html();
    var contents;
    switch(index) {
        case 1:
            contents = g1;
            break;
        case 2:
            contents = g2;
        ...
    }
    $('#galleria').html(contents);
    initiateGallery();
})
```

I guess that you're trying to clear the html of #galleria with this line:

```
$('#galleria').html();
```

You should pass an empty string to html() to clear the content:

```
$('#galleria').html('');
```

Comment: I agree with your solution, but I don't think `eval` is the devil in every case, it should be used wisely that's all.

Comment: I agree that there are situations where eval is the best alternative. But most of the uses of eval that I see are not cases where eval is used wisely.

Comment: Ahhhh yes was trying to clear the html but always miss the ('') thats working better...

Comment: Worked perfectly! Why is 'eval' evil?

Comment: There are many opinions about this but I think that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil/198031#198031) explains it quite good

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to insert the text string `'g'+index` into the HTML then I would probably suggest doing...

```
$('#galleria').html('<span>g'+index+'</span>');
```

Comment: Well you don't even know what #galleria is, it may already be a span.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `eval`method :
    $('#galleria').html(eval('g'+index));